# Debugging linked list pointers code: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

So the following code:

```
/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
 * };
 *
 */
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
  SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  SinglyLinkedListNode* temp1;
  temp1->data = data;
  temp1->next = NULL;
  temp->next = temp1;
  return temp;
}
```

So, basically I want to add "data" at the end of the linked list "head" and return the updated list. So where is the fault?

Edit: Okay I got the first mistake. But even if I replace temp!=NULL with temp->next!=NULL in the loop conditional still there's this error

Comment: `SinglyLinkedListNode* temp1; temp1->data=data;` does not work, where does `temp1` point to?

Comment: @mch, okay, I am new to this. What I thought was that I should initialise a blank variable like we declare integers as "int a; a=2;". So how do I resolve this?

Comment: What's the value of `temp` after the `while(temp!=NULL)` loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo, the pointer to the last node of the linked list?

Comment: Not only temp1, where does temp point to? (NULL)

Comment: @Pzc, why? Initially temp points to head, then after the loop it presumably points to the last node in the linked list? Why not?

Comment: `temp` points to `NULL` after the loop. The loop stops if `temp == NULL`.

Comment: Please check the edits @ThomasSablik

Comment: Please look at the edits @Pzc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for the node. Remember to clean up the allocated memory. For each call to `new` you need a call `delete`. Therefore I prefer smart pointers.

After your loop `temp` contains `NULL`. You can't dereference a null pointer.

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp1 = new SinglyLinkedListNode;
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = nullptr;
    if (!head) {
        head = temp1;
        return head;
    }
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = head;
    while(temp->next){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = temp1;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal A pointer can be implicitly converted to bool and returns false for `nullptr` and true else. `!head` is equivalent to `head == nullptr`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I understood all of what you said. But when I use your code, the following error occurs:  error: no matching function for call to ‘SinglyLinkedListNode::SinglyLinkedListNode()’

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal That means you have no default constructor. You have to call one of your constructors at the point.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal pointer value are evaluated to true iff it is not nullptr, so '''!head''' is true iff head IS nullptr

Comment: One last thing, when we write "SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = head;", does this mean any change to temp will also occur on head?

Comment: Any change on `*temp` will also occur on `*head`.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
SinglyLinkedListNode* temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL){
    temp=temp->next;
}
SinglyLinkedListNode* temp1;
temp1->data=data;
temp1->next=NULL;
temp->next=temp1;
return temp;
}
```

does not make sense. After this loop

```
while(temp!=NULL){
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

the pointer `temp` is equal to NULL. So this statement

```
temp->next=temp1;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

The pointer `temp1` was not initialized. So again these statements

```
temp1->data=data;
temp1->next=NULL;
```

invoke undefined behavior.

The user of the function does not know whether the returned pointer is the head pointer or the last pointer of the list. So it is unclear whether to assign the returned pointer to the head pointer or just to ignore the returned value.

The function can look the following way.

```
void insertNodeAtTail( SinglyLinkedListNode * &head, int data ) 
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode **current = &head;

    while ( *current != nullptr ) current = &( *current )->next;

    *current = new SinglyLinkedListNode { data, nullptr };
}
```

If in main you defined the pointer to the head node like

```
SinglyLinkedListNode *head = nullptr;
```

then a function call will look like

```
insertNodeAtTail( head, some_data );
```

Another definition of the function can look the following way

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail( SinglyLinkedListNode *head, int data ) 
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode *new_node = new SinglyLinkedListNode { data, nullptr };

    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode *current = head;

        while ( current->next != nullptr ) current = current->next;

        current->next = new_node;
    }

    return head;
}
```

In this case if in main you defined the pointer to the head node like

```
SinglyLinkedListNode *head = nullptr;
```

then the function call will look like

```
head = insertNodeAtTail( head, some_data );
```

Between these two function definitions the first function definition is preferable because there is no need to remember to assign the returned pointer to the head node.

Bear in mind that if you have a singly-linked list and want to append new nodes to the tail of the list ten it is better to define two-sided singly-linked list. In this case the list definition can look like

```
class SinglyLinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data,
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

public:

    SinglyLinkedList() = default;
    void insertNodeAtHead( int data );
    void insertNodeAtTail( int data );
    // other member functions;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It crashes here also:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* temp1;
temp1->data=data;
```

when you reach the end of the loop `while(temp!=NULL){` , here `temp` is `NULL`.
below you are using a statement like this `temp->next=temp1;` this causes crash

Comment: Thanks, please look at the edits, and please tell why are they crashing?